# I get an error fileimage in flutter when I open it

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i try to make a music player app in flutter .
i use a FlutterAudioQuery package for get all of music from storage.
i want get music artworks my cods working well but i see some problem .
also i want say i get music artworks in tow different Method android sdk >=29 and else
the first method working great the second method also working good but i have error for one music thats my error:

> FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/1575720288590' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))

and thats my codes

```
song.albumArtwork != null
                  ? CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: FileImage(File(song.albumArtwork)),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[
                          math.Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
                      child: assetsAudioPlayer.builderRealtimePlayingInfos(
                          builder: (context, tiitle) {
                        String xxx = tiitle.current.audio.audio.path;
                        String po;

                        return Icon(
                          tiitle.isPlaying == true && xxx == song.filePath
                              ? Icons.pause
                              : Icons.play_arrow,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        );
                      }))
                  : androidSDKAPI >= 29
                      ? FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
                          future: audioQuery.getArtwork(
                              type: ResourceType.SONG, id: song.id),
                          builder: (contaxt, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                              if (snapshot.data.isNotEmpty) {
                                return CircleAvatar(
                                    backgroundImage:
                                        MemoryImage(snapshot.data),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[
                                        math.Random().nextInt(
                                            Colors.primaries.length)],
                                    child: assetsAudioPlayer
                                        .builderRealtimePlayingInfos(
                                            builder: (context, tiitle) {
                                      String xxx =
                                          tiitle.current.audio.audio.path;
                                      String po;
                                      return Icon(
                                        tiitle.isPlaying == true &&
                                                xxx == song.filePath
                                            ? Icons.pause
                                            : Icons.play_arrow,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      );
                                    }));
                              }
                            }

                            // print("Got exception ${e.toString()}");
                            return CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage:
                                    AssetImage('assets/$rr.jpg'),
                                backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[
                                    math.Random()
                                        .nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
                                child: assetsAudioPlayer
                                    .builderRealtimePlayingInfos(
                                        builder: (context, tiitle) {
                                  String xxx =
                                      tiitle.current.audio.audio.path;
                                  String po;
                                  return Icon(
                                    tiitle.isPlaying == true &&
                                            xxx == song.filePath
                                        ? Icons.pause
                                        : Icons.play_arrow,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  );
                                }));

                            // if (snapshot.data == null) {

                            // }
                          },
                        )
                      : CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/$rr.jpg'),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.primaries[math.Random()
                              .nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
                          child: assetsAudioPlayer
                              .builderRealtimePlayingInfos(
                                  builder: (context, tiitle) {
                            String xxx = tiitle.current.audio.audio.path;
                            String po;
                            return Icon(
                              tiitle.isPlaying == true &&
                                      xxx == song.filePath
                                  ? Icons.pause
                                  : Icons.play_arrow,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            );
                          })),
```

i want when image cant load or cant fined path thats show a my assets pics;

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look up the file manually in file manager, I think it is not there.

Comment: yes thats true it is not there